# Random.Next() always returns same values in for loop

Tags: c#, random

I am currently writing a Program where I want all values of an array to be randomized, although the output of Random.Next() is random, it is not random inside of the for-loop.

My code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < simsToRun; i++)
            {
                Simulations[i, 0] = Simulations[i, 0] + (rand.Next(0, 3) / 100) - 0.01f; 
                Simulations[i, 1] = Simulations[i, 1] + (rand.Next(0, 3) / 100) - 0.01f; 
                Simulations[i, 2] = Simulations[i, 2] + (rand.Next(0, 3) / 10) - 0.1f; 
            }
```

An example of the values after randomization:

Simulations[0, 0] = 0.9

Simulations[0, 1] = 1.1

Simulations[0, 2] = 45

This is as expected, however, this exact pattern repeats itself throughout the loop:

Simulations[1, 0] = 0.9

Simulations[1, 1] = 1.1

Simulations[1, 2] = 45

And so on...
Is there any way to fix this?

If you need any extra information, let me know

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand.Next(0, 3) / 100` is always 0. You get an integer thats either 0,1 or 2. Then divide by 100, this gets rounded down to 0.

You want

`rand.NextDouble()` and the adjust the range of the result to match what yout need. (It returns a number from 0.0 to < 1.0)

Comment: The array is a float[,], so shouldn't this work? Also, the values do get changed randomly every time, just not inside the for-loop

Comment: @FloatyBoi `rand.Next(0, 3)` is not a float

Comment: @FloatyBoi doesnt matter what you assign zero to you still end up with zero. Plus I cannot comment on the behavior of other code that I cant see

Comment: Looking at this further it seems like you're absolutely right, it always just subtracts the values I put at the end...

Comment: The other option is to change the divisor to `100.0` so that it doesn't do `int` division and truncate.

Comment: @juharr doesnt change the fact that that will only generate 3 different random numbers 0.0, 0.01 and 0.02

Comment: @pm100 It's not obvious if the OP only wants to pick from 3 random numbers or any number between 0 and 0.03.